# PHP If statements - Getting One Result Within While Loop

Tags: php, if-statement

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I have a simple setup in which I am trying to do the following:

```
<?php
...
if ($variable == "this")
{
    echo "this";
}
elseif ($variable == "that")
{
    echo "that";
}
else
{
   echo "neither";
}
...
?>
```

In my case, I am doing the if statements within a while loop, so `$variable` may equal `this` within one iteration, and `that` within another iteration, and therefore I get both results displayed whenever `$variable` is equal to `this` or `that` - which is what I want.  So far so good.

However, if neither result is true for ALL of the `$variable` iterations, I only want to display `neither` one time (whenever all iterations of `$variable` does not equal to `this` or `that` within my while loop).  Since I am in a while loop, I end up getting `neither` multiple times, once for each time that `$variable` is not equal to either `this` or `that`.

So my question is - how do I get the result of `neither` to only appear once when none of the `$variable` iterations are equal to `this` or `that`?

EDIT:  Clarified post a bit...and here's a more complete example with my code (simplified a bit so as to not take up much space):

```
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `order`"); <-- $con is just a mysqli_connect statement.
if ($results)
{
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        $status = $obj->status;
        if ($status == "this")
        {
            echo "this"; <-- this is actually html code, but let's pretend it's just this.
        }
        elseif ($status == "that")
        {
            echo "that";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "neither";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `break;` to the `else`. That should stop the loop there.

Comment: _'$variable may equal both this and that at the same time'_ - is this some strange version of PHP for use in quantum computers?

Comment: `$variable` can't have two values at the same time. Are you sure you explained your case correctly? Or did you mean that `$variable` may be equal to `this` during one iteration, and equal to `that` on the next? In any case, providing us with more complete code (including the loop) might be helpful.

Comment: Why not use switch case instead?

Comment: I tried switch case but it ends up being the same result in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit certainly makes a lot of difference.

First, are you able to change the SQL query that you use for search? If yes, you can try this:

```
// Perform search only for the valid status, which are 'this' and 'that'
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE status IN ('this', 'that')");

if ($results)
{
    if ($results->num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo 'neither';
    }
    else
    {
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
            if ($obj->status == 'this')
            {
                echo 'this';
            }
            elseif ($obj->status == 'that')
            {
                echo 'that';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if changing the query is not an option, you will need to loop twice: Once to check whether you have at least a `this` or `that`, and second to print the actual result.

```
$has_this_or_that = false;
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `order`"); <-- $con is just a mysqli_connect statement.
if ($results)
{
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object() && ! $has_this_or_that)
    {
        $status = $obj->status;

        if ($status == 'this' || $status == 'that')
        {
            $has_this_or_that = true;
        }
    }

    if ($has_this_or_that)
    {
        // Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php
        $results->data_seek(0);

        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
            $status = $obj->status;

            if ($status == 'this')
            {
                echo 'this'; <-- this is actually html code, but let's pretend it's just this.
            }
            elseif ($status == 'that')
            {
                echo 'that';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'neither';
    }

        else
        {
            echo 'neither';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up changing the query as you suggested in the first example.  Can't believe it was so simple.  The only thing that needs correction is that
    
`$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM order WHERE status NOT IN ('this', 'that')");`

should be

`$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM order WHERE status IN ('this', 'that')");`  (remove the NOT).

Thanks again!

Comment: Oopss.. yes, you are right. It's a small logic error there. Let me fix it. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by assuming nothing has been matched, then changing that when something does match. Then after the loop if nothing matched, it will still be set to false. See examples below. I made it a function to quickly demonstrate what happens when something did match, and what happens when none of them matched. Typically functions should not echo data ;)

```
<?php

echo 'checking 0-5'.PHP_EOL;
$check = range(0,5);
check($check);

echo 'checking 10-12'.PHP_EOL;
$check = range(10,12);
check($check);

function check($check){
  $noneMatched = true;
  foreach($check AS $i){
     if($i==2){
        echo 'first'.PHP_EOL;
        $noneMatched = false;
     }elseif($i==4){
        echo 'second'.PHP_EOL;
        $noneMatched = false;
     }
  }

  if($noneMatched === true){
   echo 'none matched'.PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

https://eval.in/402729

Output:

```
checking 0-5
first
second
checking 10-12
none matched
```

Comment: Thanks Jessica.  I wouldn't think that this solution requires a function, but I can follow the logic.  Will give it a try when I have some time tomorrow and report back.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, I just wanted to show each situation without retyping the code. Let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check first if `'this'` and `'that'` values exist in your array. if they don't, just echo a single 'neither'. If either one of them exist, just go on with executing your while loop.

```
if(!in_array('this', $your_array) && !in_array('that', $your_array)) {
    echo 'neither';
} else {
    // insert your while loop here
}
```

EDIT: it should be an `&&` operator since neither of them should exist for the `while` loop to execute

Answer (score 0):

Update a variable if you ever find this or that, then do something outside of the loop if the variable was not updated.

```
<?php
$foo = false;
...
if ($variable == "this")
{
    echo "this";
    $foo = true;
}
elseif ($variable == "that")
{
    echo "that";
    $foo = true;
}
...
If (!$foo) {

    echo "none of them are that or this";
```

}
    ?>

If any of them are that or this the if statement outiside of the loop will not run. This means that if none of them are that or this the output will be shown.

Comment: This would solve the problem of running the else statement one time, but how do I only get it to only display when all iterations of `$variable` do not equal `this` or `that` within the while loop?  This solution would still produce one `neither` result if one of the iterations of `$variable` returned a `this` or `that`, and I don't want `neither` to appear if any `$variable` iteration returns a `this` or `that`.  Hope that makes sense.